# Changing UILabel text causes movable UIImageView objects to revert back to original position

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel, nstimer

I have created a storyboard with multiple movable (using pan gesture recognisers) `UIImageView` objects, that are hidden by default. I have a `UIButton`, that when pressed, generates random X and Y positions for the buttons to be moved to as follows:

```
// Places each puzzle piece at a random location on the screen
for puzzlePiece in puzzlePieces {

        // Generate a random X position for the new center point of the puzzle,
        // so that the piece is on the screen. Must convert to UInt and then CGFloat
        var randomXPosition: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt(114 + arc4random_uniform(796)))

        // Generate a random Y position for the new center point of the puzzle,
        // so that the piece is on the screen. Must convert to UInt and then CGFloat.
        var randomYPosition: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt(94 + arc4random_uniform(674)))

        puzzlePiece.frame = CGRect(x: randomXPosition, y: randomYPosition, width: puzzlePiece.frame.width, height: puzzlePiece.frame.height)
}
```

After the `UIImageViews` are moved to random positions, they are un-hidden, and a `UILabel` displaying a timer begins to keep track of time, as follows:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimerLabel"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The problem is that whenever the `NSTimer` calls the "`updateTimerLabel`" method and the `UILabel's` text is modified, ALL of the `UIImageViews` revert to their default location as specified on the Storyboard (plus any transformations as a result of panning). Specifically, the last line of this method causes the issue:

```
func updateTimerLabel() {

    secondsElapsed++;

    var numSecondsToDisplay = secondsElapsed % 60
    var numMinutesToDisplay = ((secondsElapsed - numSecondsToDisplay) % 3600) / 60
    var numHoursToDisplay = (secondsElapsed - numSecondsToDisplay - numMinutesToDisplay) / 3600

    var secondsToDisplay = String(format: "%02d", numSecondsToDisplay)
    var minutesToDisplay = String(format: "%02d", numMinutesToDisplay)
    var hoursToDisplay = String(format: "%02d", numHoursToDisplay)

    timerLabel.text! = "Timer: \(hoursToDisplay):\(minutesToDisplay):\(secondsToDisplay)"
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to prevent the `UIImageViews` from reverting from their random positions to their default Storyboard positions when changing the `UILabel's` text.

Comment: That's strange... So you're saying that when you remove that last line, "timerLabel.text! = "Timer:...", everything works?

Comment: Yeah, if I comment that out it's fine. The UIImageView's don't change positions.

Comment: Auto Layout is running and repositioning your objects. Turn off Auto Layout.

Comment: @vacawama That fixed it! Thanks! If you add that as an answer I'll toss you accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto Layout is running and repositioning your objects. Turn off Auto Layout and your objects will stay where you put them.